# ng-repeat with dynamic filter

Tags: angularjs

I have 3 dynamic ng-repeat with one global search field.

I will create a filter which shows the user only the remaining fields after he do a textsearch.

For example there are 2 Objects:

name: Robert age: 20   and   name: Tom color: red

So first the filters should be name, age, color but when I do a search with my global search field for Tom the filters array should include only name, color.

I think about using an onChange event to push the filtered data to a function who checks for redundant fields and updates the filter array. But I can't found something.

```
<tr ng-repeat="device in filtered = (tables[categoryKey].data | filter:textSearch)" class="devices-item">
</tr>
```

Do you have any hints for me? Or should I use a filter for pushing to filters array?

**EDIT:**

Now I have get the Items with this simple filter:

```
$scope.isFilter = function(filtered) {
    angular.forEach(filtered.data, function(value, key) {
        if($scope.availableFilters.indexOf(key) == -1) {
            $scope.availableFilters.push(key);
        } 
    })  
    return filtered;
};
```

But I have no idea how I can delete them from array when they are removed by the global text filter.

Comment: to remove an item from an array: `yourArray.splice(index, 1)`

Comment: yes, I know...but don't know which indicator I should use for remove.